# Free RTE [Rich text editor] help needed integrating it

Tags: php, html, rte

Working on a PHP /html content management system and found Free RTE online which is a free rich text editor.
Have no idea how to integrate it into my own stuff.

There are sample codes with it alrite, but they are not very clear.

Anyone used it before or have any knowledge of integrating it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't but i use http://www.ecardmax.com/index.php?step=Hoteditor which is in my opinion nice and easy to use, if it helps

Answer (score 1):

RTE are usually very simple to embed. The process is to give an ID to your textarea and then initialize your RTE through Javascript calling for this textarea's ID. Javascript will transform this textarea into a fully-featured RTE on page load.

Usually well documented on RTE's examples and howtos. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What is an URL of that free editor you are talking about? Did you try for example FCKEditor? www.fckeditor.net

Comment: its freerichtexteditor.com yeah im just looking at these ones now - cheers lads!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys,

I ended up going for FCKeditor which is now embedded and functioning.
It took a while to figure out how to link it into my own stuff tho, but the examples that came with it helped.

Turns out you just plant the editors directory tree into your primary working folder [or wherever] and edit the 'include' functions [php] to link the editor files to your own project files.

Heh and i found this website by accident like, thumbs up for stackoverflow!!!